# React Native error - Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am very new to React Native. I've been following along with a YouTube tutorial, when I tried one of their examples I get the following error message in the iPhone emulator:

**Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

Here are the screen shots of my code.. (It's not much code at all)

[index.ios.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F7u3.png)

[viewContainer.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3gcc.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Paste your code here, don't post it as image.Go to `ViewContainer.js`, into the class create constructor method where you will pass the props and using the super keyword inherit them from parent class
`constructor(props) { super(props); }`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, and sorry about posting them as pics this is my first post wasn't sure of the best practices. So where exactly in the method would I put `{ super(props); }` ?

Comment: You should try to add this into the ViewContainer Class `constructor(props) { super(props); }`, so basically you can put it just before `render()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got rid of that error! However now im getting an error: **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.default.StyleSheet.create')**  any idea why that is?

Comment: It's happened because you didn't import `StyleSheet` from 'react-native' in ViewContainer.js

Comment: You are the best! It's working, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'll post those things as answer, so you can accept It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ViewContainer.js` needs to access props that are defined in other class (parent class) you can inherit those things by calling the `super()` method in the constructor of your child class.

```
class ViewContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // Rest of the code...
  }
}
```

Other thing is that you are missing the import of `StyleSheet` from 'react-native' in ViewContainer so that's why you were getting error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_react2.default.StyleSheet.create')